# scroll down bottom when new message append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here i append my new message.

```
<ul class="chat messages" id="get_AllMsg" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 650px">

</ul>
```

After my success ajax call

```
 var pre_content = $('.messages').html();
    var new_content = '<li class="clearfix">';
    new_content += '<span class="chat-img"><img src="" alt="User Avatar"></span>';
    new_content += '<div class="chat-body clearfix">
    <div class="header"><strong class="primary-font">' + name + '</strong> </div> <p>' + data.message + '</p> </div>';
    var content = pre_content + new_content;
        $('.messages').html(content);
```

Here i use jquery to scroll, i want to auto scroll bottom when new message sent

```
        $('.messages').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.messages').scrollHeight
        }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sum height of each `<li>` element and then use it. Here is an example:

```js
var ht = 0;
$(".messages li").each(function() {
  ht += $(this).height();
});
$(".messages").animate({scrollTop: ht});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="chat messages" id="get_AllMsg" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 30px">
  <li>example</li>
  <li>example</li>
  <li>example</li>
  <li>example</li>
  <li>example</li>
  <li>example</li>
  <li>example</li>
  <li>example</li>
  <li>example</li>
  <li>example</li>
  <li>example</li>
  <li>example</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$('.messages')[0].scrollHeight` instead of `$('.messages').scrollHeight`

```js
$('.messages').animate({
  scrollTop: $('.messages')[0].scrollHeight
}, 1000);
```

```css
.messages {
width: 200px;
background: red;
}

li {
height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="chat messages" id="get_AllMsg" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 650px">
<li></li>
</ul>
```